# Duplicate in vba

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Say I have a table with 4 columns: Id(col23), Group(col 5), Option (col24) & value (col 12). This is a simplified example and the col numbers are the numbers in my actual spreadsheet. What I am trying to do is remove duplicate rows when there is more than one row with the same id in the id column. This bit is working using the following code:

```
Sub data()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

    If Cells(i, 12).Value < Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & Range(Cells(1, 23), Cells(LastRow, 23)).Address _
            & "=" & Cells(i, 23).Address & "," & Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(LastRow, 12)).Address & "))") Then

        Rows(i).Delete

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

However I noticed that for some records the id is the same and also the value is the same. This means that I am left with a few duplicates. To get rid of these I would also like to run a test to compare what is in the Options Column. Each cell in this column will have one of the following options: OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, ordered by importance respectfully. The one of most importance should be kept and the other others removed.

What I am also trying to do is count and record how many duplicates from each group have been removed. Say there are 3 groups: GroupA, GroupB & GroupC, I would like to have an array and each time a duplicate is removed the code should check which group it belongs to and add one to that element of the array.
Do you know how I can modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare and initialse an array at the top of your code (below say Dim I as Long) like this:

```
    Dim yourArray(3) As Long

    yourArray(1) = 0 'GroupA
    yourArray(2) = 0 'GroupB
    yourArray(3) = 0 'GroupC
```

Then inside your IF statement just before you delete the row add something like this:

```
if(cells(i, 5).value = "GroupA") then yourArray(1) = yourArray(1) + 1
if(cells(i, 5).value = "GroupB") then yourArray(2) = yourArray(2) + 1
if(cells(i, 5).value = "GroupC") then yourArray(3) = yourArray(3) + 1
```

There are neater ways to do this but this will get the job done